# Python evaluating/compiling a string

Tags: python

I want to evaluate a string to accomplish the following.  The string will be coming from an xml config file.  This is how I would configure a serial option without a config file:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(/dev/ttyUSB0)
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_MARK
...configure other options
```

Now this is the equivalent of what I want to do but...

```
   str = "PARITY_MARK"
   ser.parity = some_wrapper("serial." + str)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `getattr`?

```
getattr(serial, 'PARITY_MARK') == serial.PARITY_MARK
```